# How to change String ArrayList into a Double ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception, paintcomponent

Every time I try to run my file to display a graph it gets the majority of teh program done, up until to the GraphAtOrigin Class. This is where an error is thrown, saying the "IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0". So I believe there is something wrong with the wat I converted the domainList String ArrayList to the domainNumList Double ArrayListsome or a problem when I try to get the double array from the CreateGraphInterior Class. What do I need to do to prevent this exception and allow the code to run?

I have already tried casting the String ArrayList to a Double ArrayList with varies techniques, but if you have a better way let me know.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class GraphProject {
  public static JTextField depStart = new JTextField(10);
  public static JTextField depEnd = new JTextField(10);
  public static JTextField indStart = new JTextField(10);
  public static JTextField indEnd = new JTextField(10);
  public static JFrame main = new JFrame("Input The Graph Scale");
  public static JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
  // for the input of Title, subtitle, and units
  public static JFrame getInfo = new JFrame("Input The Graph Information");
  public static JTextField gTitle = new JTextField(10);
  public static JTextField gSubTitle = new JTextField(10);
  public static JTextField depAxisUnit = new JTextField(10);
  public static JTextField indAxisUnit = new JTextField(10);
  public static JButton submitInfo = new JButton("Submit");
  public static boolean selected = false;
  public static boolean noSelected = false;
  public static int dataLength;
  public static double domainMax;
  public static double rangeMax;
  public static ArrayList<String> rangeList = new ArrayList<String>();
  public static ArrayList<String> domainList = new ArrayList<String>();




  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

    // Used to print out the data from the txt file
/*
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("DataSetValues.txt");
    int i;
    while((i=fr.read()) != -1){
      System.out.print((char)i);
    }
*/
    readData1();
    readData2();
    ObtainGraphInfo getGraphInfo = new ObtainGraphInfo();
    getGraphInfo.graphInfo();
  }

  // Creates the Option Pane for user to input axis start and end positions
  public static void axisPositions(){
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    boolean yes = false;
    boolean no = false;
    JCheckBox startAtOrigin = new JCheckBox("Yes", yes);
        startAtOrigin.addItemListener(
        new ItemListener() {
          public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
              selected = true;
              makeGraph();
              System.out.println("run the method to make the points graph at origin (0,0)");
              main.dispose();
            }
          }
          });


    JCheckBox dontStartAtOrigin = new JCheckBox("No", no);
      dontStartAtOrigin.addItemListener(
        new ItemListener() {
          public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
              noSelected = true;
              makeGraph();
              System.out.println("run the method to stop the points from graphing at the origin (0,0)");
              main.dispose();
            }
          }
          });


    JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
    gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
    main.setContentPane(gui);
    main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    gui.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);
    gui.add(controls, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    labels.add(new JLabel("Do you want the points to begin graphing "));
    controls.add(startAtOrigin);
    labels.add(new JLabel("      with the origin (0,0)? "));
    controls.add(dontStartAtOrigin);
    /*labels.add(new JLabel("Independent Axis Start Position: "));
    controls.add(indStart);
    labels.add(new JLabel("Independent Axis End Position: "));
    controls.add(indEnd);*/


  // Codes for the action performed when the submit button is pressed
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       submit = (JButton)e.getSource();
       main.dispose();
       makeGraph();
                }
              });

          gui.add(submit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
          main.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(submit);
          main.pack();
          submit.setVisible(false);
          main.setVisible(true);
  }

  // Read the data from txt file and put it into an arrayList then separate into domain and range arrayLists
    public static ArrayList<String> readData1() throws Exception{
      ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
      File file = new File("C://Users//wildc//Desktop//ToMac//Computer Science//Java Programs//GraphProjectFolder//testValues.txt");
      Scanner scanData = new Scanner(file);
      try{

        while (scanData.hasNext()){
            dataList.add(scanData.next());
        }
        int position = 0;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < ((dataList.size()/2) + 1) ; counter ++ ) {
          domainList.add(dataList.get(position));
          position = (position + 2);

        }

        scanData.close();

        //Creating domainList


    } catch(Exception e) {
      //System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
      System.out.println("This error ran 1");
    }
    System.out.println(domainList.size() + " This is the Domain SIzeS");
    System.out.println(domainList + "This is the domain List");
    System.out.println(dataList + "This is the data list");
    dataLength = domainList.size();
    domainMax = Double.parseDouble(Collections.max(domainList));
    System.out.println(domainMax + " : Domain max");
  return domainList;
    }
    public static ArrayList<String> readData2() throws Exception{
      ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
      File file = new File("C://Users//wildc//Desktop//ToMac//Computer Science//Java Programs//GraphProjectFolder//testValues.txt");
      Scanner scanData = new Scanner(file);
      try{


      while (scanData.hasNext()){
          dataList.add(scanData.next());
      }
      scanData.close();
      //Creating rangeList

      int position = 1;
      for (int counter = 0; counter < ((dataList.size()/2) + 1) ; counter ++ ) {
        rangeList.add(dataList.get(position));
        position = (position + 2);

      }
      // Was used to replace a certain element with another (incomplete)

    }catch(Exception e) {
      //System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
      System.out.println("This error ran 2");
    }
    rangeMax = Double.parseDouble(Collections.max(rangeList));
    System.out.println(rangeMax + " : Range max");
    return rangeList;
    }

  //Displaying the frame for the graph to be on
  public static void makeGraph(){
    JFrame graph = new JFrame();
    graph.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    graph.setSize(1000,1000);
    graph.setTitle("Test Graph Scales");
    graph.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


    CreateGraphOutline graphFrame = new CreateGraphOutline();
    CreateGraphInterior verticalLines = new CreateGraphInterior();
    graph.add(graphFrame);
    graph.setVisible(true);
    graph.add(verticalLines);
    graph.setVisible(true);
  //  TestFile testingAction = new TestFile();
    //String[] testing = {"1","2","3"};
  //  testingAction.main(testing);

    CreateGraphAttributes graphAttributes = new CreateGraphAttributes();
    graph.add(graphAttributes);

    GraphAtOrigin graphWithOriginStart = new GraphAtOrigin();
    if (selected == true) {

      graph.add(graphWithOriginStart);
      graph.setVisible(true);
    }
    /*GraphNotAtOrigin graphNotWithOriginStart = new GraphAtOrigin();
    if (noSelected == true) {
      graph.add(graphNotWithOriginStart);
      graph.setVisible(true);
    }
    makeGraph();

  }*/







}}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;



public class CreateGraphAttributes extends JComponent{

  public static String whereToStart;
  public static String graphTitle;
  public static String graphSubTitle;
  public static String depUnit;
  public static String indUnit;
  public static String depTitle;
  public static String indTitle;
  public static FontMetrics metrics;

  public void paintComponent(Graphics image) {
    Graphics2D graph = (Graphics2D) image;
    ObtainGraphInfo graphSpecifics = new ObtainGraphInfo();
    ArrayList graphInformation = (ArrayList)graphSpecifics.setGraphAttributes();
    graphTitle = graphInformation.get(0).toString();
    graphSubTitle = graphInformation.get(1).toString();
    depUnit = graphInformation.get(2).toString();
    indUnit = graphInformation.get(3).toString();
    depTitle = graphInformation.get(4).toString();
    indTitle = graphInformation.get(5).toString();

  //  System.out.println(depAxisStartText + "," + indAxisStartText);
    // title
    Rectangle titleSpace = new Rectangle(200,50,600,200);
    Font titleFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD | Font.PLAIN, 22);
    titleText(graph, graphTitle, titleSpace, titleFont);
    // subtitle
    Rectangle subTitleSpace = new Rectangle(200,100,600,150);
    Font subTitleFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);
    subTitleText(graph, graphSubTitle, subTitleSpace, subTitleFont);
    // dependent axis 500, 700
    Rectangle depTitleSpace = new Rectangle(200,600,550,150);
    depAxisText(graph, depTitle, depUnit, depTitleSpace, subTitleFont);
    // independent axis 10, 400
    Rectangle indTitleSpace = new Rectangle(0,200,100,400);
    indAxisText(graph, indTitle, indUnit, indTitleSpace, subTitleFont);




    Point bottomLeftPoint = new Point(200,600);
    Point bottomRightPoint = new Point(800,600); // 600px difference

    Point leftBottomPoint = new Point(200,600);
    Point leftTopPoint = new Point(200,200); // 400px difference


    Point rightBottomPoint = new Point(800,600);
    Point rightTopPoint = new Point(800,200);


    Point topLeftPoint = new Point(200,200);
    Point topRightPoint = new Point(800,200); // 600px difference



  }

  public void titleText(Graphics2D g, String text, Rectangle rect, Font font) {
      // Get the FontMetrics
      metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
      // Determine the X coordinate for the text
      int x = rect.x + (rect.width - metrics.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
      // Determine the Y coordinate for the text (note we add the ascent, as in java 2d 0 is top of the screen)
      int y = rect.y + ((rect.height - metrics.getHeight()) / 2) + metrics.getAscent();
      // Set the font
      g.setFont(font);
      // Draw the String
      g.drawString(text, x, y);
  }
  public void subTitleText(Graphics2D g, String text, Rectangle rect, Font font) {
      // Get the FontMetrics
      metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
      // Determine the X coordinate for the text
      int x = rect.x + (rect.width - metrics.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
      // Determine the Y coordinate for the text (note we add the ascent, as in java 2d 0 is top of the screen)
      int y = rect.y + ((rect.height - metrics.getHeight()) / 2) + metrics.getAscent();
      // Set the font
      g.setFont(font);
      // Draw the String
      g.drawString(text, x, y);
  }

  public void depAxisText(Graphics2D g, String text, String text2, Rectangle rect, Font font) {
      // Get the FontMetrics
      metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
      // Determine the X coordinate for the text
      int x = rect.x + (rect.width - metrics.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
      // Determine the Y coordinate for the text (note we add the ascent, as in java 2d 0 is top of the screen)
      int y = rect.y + ((rect.height - metrics.getHeight()) / 2) + metrics.getAscent();
      // Set the font
      g.setFont(font);
      // Create correct text structure
      text = (text + " (" + text2 + ")");
      // Draw the String
      g.drawString(text, x, y);
  }

  public void indAxisText(Graphics2D g, String text, String text2, Rectangle rect, Font font) {
      // Get the FontMetrics
      metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
      // Determine the X coordinate for the text
      int x = rect.x + (rect.width - metrics.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
      // Determine the Y coordinate for the text (note we add the ascent, as in java 2d 0 is top of the screen)
      int y = rect.y + ((rect.height - metrics.getHeight()) / 2) + metrics.getAscent();
      // Set the font
      g.setFont(font);
      // Create correct text structure
      text = (text + " (" + text2 + ")");
      // Draw the String
      g.drawString(text, x, y);
  }



}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class CreateGraphOutline extends JComponent{
  public void paintComponent(Graphics image, boolean selected) {
    Graphics2D graph = (Graphics2D) image;
    Point bottomLeftPoint = new Point(200,600);
    Point bottomRightPoint = new Point(800,600); // 600px difference
    Line2D.Double depAxis = new Line2D.Double(bottomLeftPoint,bottomRightPoint);
    BasicStroke lineThickness = new BasicStroke(4);
    graph.setStroke(lineThickness);
    graph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    graph.draw(depAxis);
    Point leftBottomPoint = new Point(200,600);
    Point leftTopPoint = new Point(200,200); // 400px difference
    Line2D.Double indAxis = new Line2D.Double(leftBottomPoint,leftTopPoint);
    graph.draw(indAxis);
    Point rightBottomPoint = new Point(800,600);
    Point rightTopPoint = new Point(800,200);
    Line2D.Double rightIndAxis = new Line2D.Double(rightBottomPoint,rightTopPoint);
    graph.draw(rightIndAxis);
    Point topLeftPoint = new Point(200,200);
    Point topRightPoint = new Point(800,200); // 600px difference
    Line2D.Double topDepAxis = new Line2D.Double(topLeftPoint,topRightPoint);
    graph.draw(topDepAxis);



  }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class ObtainGraphInfo {

  public static JFrame getInfo = new JFrame("Input The Graph Information");
  public static JTextField gTitle = new JTextField(10);
  public static JTextField gSubTitle = new JTextField(10);
  public static JTextField depAxisUnit = new JTextField(10);
  public static JTextField indAxisUnit = new JTextField(10);
  public static JTextField depAxisTitle = new JTextField(10);
  public static JTextField indAxisTitle = new JTextField(10);
  public static JButton submitInfo = new JButton("Submit");
  public static GraphProject mainFile = new GraphProject();
  public static ArrayList gAttributes;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }
// Prompt the user for the title, subtitle, and units of the Graph
  public static void graphInfo(){


    getInfo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
    gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
    getInfo.setContentPane(gui);
    getInfo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    gui.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);
    gui.add(controls, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    labels.add(new JLabel("Graph Title: "));
    controls.add(gTitle);
    labels.add(new JLabel("Graph Sub-Title: "));
    controls.add(gSubTitle);
    labels.add(new JLabel("Dependent Axis Unit: "));
    controls.add(depAxisUnit);
    labels.add(new JLabel("Independent Axis Unit: "));
    controls.add(indAxisUnit);
    labels.add(new JLabel("Dependent Axis Title: "));
    controls.add(depAxisTitle);
    labels.add(new JLabel("Independent Axis Title: "));
    controls.add(indAxisTitle);


  // Codes for the action performed when the submit button is pressed
    submitInfo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       submitInfo = (JButton)e.getSource();
       if (gTitle.getText().equals("")) {
          Component alert = new JFrame();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure each field has an input", "Complete The Graph Information Fields!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          } else {
            if (gSubTitle.getText().equals("")) {
              Component alert = new JFrame();
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure each field has an input", "Complete The Graph Information Fields!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else{
              if (depAxisUnit.getText().equals("")) {
                Component alert = new JFrame();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure each field has an input", "Complete The Graph Information Fields!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
              } else{
                if (indAxisUnit.getText().equals("")) {
                  Component alert = new JFrame();
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure each field has an input", "Complete The Graph Information Fields!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                  if (depAxisTitle.getText().equals("")) {
                    Component alert = new JFrame();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure each field has an input", "Complete The Graph Information Fields!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                  } else {
                    if (indAxisTitle.getText().equals("")) {
                      Component alert = new JFrame();
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure each field has an input", "Complete The Graph Information Fields!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    } else{
                  String graphTitle = gTitle.getText();
                  String graphSubTitle = gSubTitle.getText();
                  String dependentAxisUnit = depAxisUnit.getText();
                  String independentAxisUnit = indAxisUnit.getText();
                  String dependentAxisTitle = depAxisTitle.getText();
                  String independentAxisTitle = indAxisTitle.getText();
                  ArrayList graphAttributes = new ArrayList<String>();
                  graphAttributes.add(graphTitle);
                  graphAttributes.add(graphSubTitle);
                  graphAttributes.add(dependentAxisUnit);
                  graphAttributes.add(independentAxisUnit);
                  graphAttributes.add(dependentAxisTitle);
                  graphAttributes.add(independentAxisTitle);
                  getInfo.dispose();
                  makeGraphAttributes(graphAttributes);
                  mainFile.axisPositions();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }}});

          gui.add(submitInfo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
          getInfo.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(submitInfo);
          getInfo.pack();
          getInfo.setVisible(true);

  }
  public static void makeGraphAttributes(ArrayList<String> graphAttributes){
    gAttributes = (ArrayList) graphAttributes.clone();
    System.out.println(gAttributes);
    setGraphAttributes();

  }
  public static ArrayList<String> setGraphAttributes(){
    return gAttributes;
  }
}
```

```
// This is the Text File Used 
0.281 0.0487
0.396 0.727
0.522   0.974
0.639   0.121
0.774   0.145
```

```
// This class creates the Double ArrayList

public class CreateGraphInterior extends JComponent{ 

  public static ArrayList<Double> domainNumList = new ArrayList<Double>();
  public static ArrayList<Double> rangeNumList = new ArrayList<Double>();
  public static ArrayList<String> domainList = new ArrayList<String>();
  public static ArrayList<String> rangeList = new ArrayList<String>();
  public static GraphProject main = new GraphProject(); // this is where the original domainList and rangeList are found
  public static int dataSize;
  public static double domMax;
  public static double ranMax;

public void paintComponent(Graphics image) {
    main.dataLength = dataSize;
    main.domainMax = domMax;
    main.rangeMax = ranMax;




    makeLists();

    Graphics2D graph = (Graphics2D) image;
    int domAxisPos = 200;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 9; counter++ ) {
      Point topPoint = new Point(domAxisPos,200);
      Point bottomPoint = new Point(domAxisPos,620);
      Line2D.Double verticalLines = new Line2D.Double(bottomPoint,topPoint);
      BasicStroke lineThickness = new BasicStroke(2);
      graph.setStroke(lineThickness);
      graph.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      graph.draw(verticalLines);
      domAxisPos = domAxisPos + 75;
    }
    int ranAxisPos = 600;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 9; counter++ ) {
      Point leftPoint = new Point(180,ranAxisPos);
      Point rightPoint = new Point(800,ranAxisPos);
      Line2D.Double horizontalLines = new Line2D.Double(leftPoint,rightPoint);
      BasicStroke lineThickness = new BasicStroke(2);
      graph.setStroke(lineThickness);
      graph.setColor(Color.GRAY);
      graph.draw(horizontalLines);
      ranAxisPos = ranAxisPos - 50;
    }

    if (main.selected == true) {
      GraphAtOrigin graphWithOrigin = new GraphAtOrigin();
    }
    if (main.noSelected == true) {
      System.out.println("Its false");
      ranAxisPos = 600;
      double domLabel = 0;
      for (int counter = 0; counter < 9; counter++ ) {
        graph.drawString(Double.toString(domLabel), domAxisPos, 650);
        domLabel = domLabel + 2.0;
        domAxisPos = domAxisPos - 50;
      }
    }

  }


public static void makeLists(){
    try{
    domainList = main.readData1();
    System.out.println(domainList + " This is domain list");
    rangeList = main.readData2();
    System.out.println(rangeList + " This is range list");
    int count = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < (main.dataLength + 1) ; counter++) {
      try {

        //Convert String to Double, and store it into Double array list.
        String domNumber = domainList.get(count);
        double domNumber2 = Double.parseDouble(domNumber);
        String ranNumber = rangeList.get(count);
        double ranNumber2 = Double.parseDouble(ranNumber);
        domainNumList.add(domNumber2);
        rangeNumList.add(ranNumber2);
        count = count + 1;
      } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        //System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
        System.out.println("This error ran");
      }


    }}catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Error arose");
    }
  }
}
```

```
// This is where I try to use the Double ArrayList

public class GraphAtOrigin extends JComponent{
  public static GraphProject main = new GraphProject();
  public static CreateGraphInterior graphInterior = new CreateGraphInterior();

  // make regular unit into pixel unit
  public static double oneDomPX = (domMax / 600);
  public static double oneRanPX = (ranMax / 400);

  public static ArrayList<Double> domainNumList = new ArrayList<Double>();;
  public static ArrayList<Double> rangeNumList = new ArrayList<Double>();;

public static void plotPoints(){

    domainNumList = graphInterior.domainNumList; // error occurs here
    rangeNumList = graphInterior.rangeNumList;
    int domPointPos = 0;
    int ranPointPos = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < (main.dataLength + 1); counter++) {

      // X data point
      double domNum = domainNumList.get(domPointPos);
      //A what to add to 200
      double domAdd = domNum / oneDomPX;
      // newX make the point relavent to the graphs location
      double domPoint = domAdd + 200;
      // make domPoint integer to be used on point method
      int newDomPoint = (int)domPoint;
      // subtract half the thickness of point to make it graph at the points center
      newDomPoint = newDomPoint - 3;

      // X data point
      double ranNum = graphInterior.rangeNumList.get(ranPointPos);
      //A what to add to 200
      double ranAdd = ranNum / oneRanPX;
      // newX make the point relavent to the graphs location
      double ranPoint = 600 - ranAdd;
      // make domPoint integer to be used on point method
      int newRanPoint = (int)ranPoint;
      // subtract half the thickness of point to make it graph at the points center
      newRanPoint = newRanPoint - 3;

      graph.fillOval(newDomPoint,newRanPoint,6,6);
      domPointPos++;
      ranPointPos++;
    }
  }
}
```

The output should then allow the for loops to execute and draw data points, but the exception is thrown and the program doesn't complete.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling the method:makeLists()?

Comment: I wasn't going to add a lot of the file so I left out the paintComponent() class at first, but just added it. That is where I call the makeLists().

Comment: I don't think the problem is in your conversion code, necessarily, because that looks okay. But somewhere along the line, you get the exception because you are trying to reference the first element (0) in a list that contains no elements, so the code that adds those elements to the `ArrayList` somehow did not get driven by that point. Are you sure that everything is happening in the right order? It's a little hard to tell because you seem to have left out a good chunk of your code.

Comment: @Logan Tucker - Can you please post the GraphProject too? Thank you.

Comment: I agree with David. You probably have left few important parts of your code.

Comment: Can you please post the StackTrace?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is at:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < (main.dataLength + 1) ; counter++) {
```

If the dataLength is 0 then this will run once and perform a `get(0)` which will throw the exception you have shown.

However if all you want to do is to convert a list of strings to a list of doubles, then you could use:

```
domainList.stream().map(Double::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you wish to quietly skip invalid strings then there is a long explanation of the regexp to use in the javadoc for `Double`. A simple version might be:

```
Pattern doublePattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
List<Double> result = domainList.stream()
    .filter(doublePattern::matches).map(Double::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ok, do I put this in a for loop? and do I set ```domainList.stream().map(Double::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());``` = to a Double ArrayList?

Comment: No you don't need a loop. Assign the expression I gave to a `List<Double>` and you're done.

Comment: whenever I try to create a ```List<Double>``` I make is like this ```  public static List<Double> domainNumList = new List<Double>();``` then later when I assign the list a value, in this case ```domainList.stream().map(Double::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());``` the compiler says 'error: type List does not take parameters'. What do I do?

Comment: @LoganTucker `List` is an interface, not an implementation. So you need to construct an implementation of a list (linked list, array list etc.). Read through the chapter on collections in the Java tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/